# 2 way switch operates opposite to my preference

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch, uk

I have two sets of 2 way switches in my new home but I prefer the lights to be off when both ends are in the "off" (as compared to regular switches) position. Conveniently there is one double 2 way switch that controls both downstairs and upstairs hall lights. I turned the MCBs for all the lights off and took this photo:

[image: double 2 way switch]

In order to make the switches off in the "off" position is the basic principle just to swap the blue and yellow wires from each cable?

Edit: Thanks to @JimStewart I realised that I needed to check one of the other switches to confirm the wiring arrangement, so here it is:

[image: one of the remote switches]

So my understanding is now that I need to swap the red and blue wires from each cable on the first switch, right? What other steps (aside from turning the power off again) should I take for maximum safety?

Comment: Hi and welcome to DIY. So you want the lights to be ON if *either* switch is ON? Or do you want the position of the switch for ON to be different?

Comment: @P2000 I want the lights to be on if exactly one switch is on, whereas currently they are off if exactly one switch is off.

Comment: Ok yes then EdBeal's answer is what you need. One of the switches will be reversed accomplishing, I believe, what you need. You realize, on&on will be off, like off&off.

Comment: In the US dual switches that toggle a load are not labeled ON when up and OFF when down. There are two ways the two switches can be properly wired: (1) load is powered only when the switches are set the same--either up or down, and (2) load is powered only when switches are set differently--one up and one down. Surely, this is the arrangement in the UK. This means that one cannot tell from the position of only one switch whether the load is powered or not.

Comment: @JimStewart I understand, but my question is about switching the wiring from (1) to (2).

Comment: If you want a switch that insures the load is off when that switch is down, then you must have a simple switch in series either with the line or the load. But if that switch was up, it would not necessarily mean the load was powered if other switches are also in series. Neil, exactly what exactly do you want to achieve here?

Comment: @JimStewart Well, you described two ways, and my wiring currently uses one of them, and I want it to use the other way. It seemed simple enough to me but I'm not the best communicator, so sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: My fault, sometimes I belabor a question.

Comment: One final point is that there are double throw switches which have an indicator light to show whether the load is powered or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a discussion (UK) asserting that there are two different ways of wiring a pair of double throw switches to allow toggle control of a load. However, probably either way can be set the way the OP wants by switching the non-common connections at exactly one switch.

https://www.electronicshub.org/2-way-switch-wiring/

This article points out that these switches break one connection before making the other. So if one switch is set in the middle, then the load is unpowered no matter what position the other is in. At least this is how these work in our house.

EDIT1
I am pretty sure that one can determine which arrangement is present by using a non-contact voltage tester on the switch, if the tester is sensitive enough to detect voltage in the box by touching to the outside. In the new "standard" arrangement line voltage is always present in both switch boxes even if one switch is set in the intermediate position (where the common is not connected to either "L" (traveler in US parlance)). In the old "alternative" arrangement this is not true. I have not yet formulated an exact detailed procedure.

EDIT3 Under a different assumption about the response of the non contact voltage tester, here is another test. The assumption is that due to the design of these switches when the tester touches the outside center of the toggle, the non contact tester signals voltage present if the common is hot, and does not signal when the common is not hot.

In the old 2-wire control arrangement, the load is unpowered, if and only if, the common in the switch next to the load is not energized. In the new standard 3-wire arrangement in the switch next to the load the common is energized in one load off position and not energized in the other load off position.

Also in the 2-wire arrangement in the box with the line hot the common is always energized, whereas in the 3-wire arrangement this common is energized in some switch positions and not in others.

Separately note (as the article states) that the three wire arrangement has one more wire in the section of cable connecting the two switch boxes. Including the neutral the 3-wire control cable will have four insulated conductors, compared to three insulated conductors for the 2-wire control arrangement.

In spite of the claims in the article linked to, right now I can't see any comparative benefit to the 3-wire arrangement.

**EDIT4** As I understand it the OP wants the switches connected so that the light is powered when the switches are set differently (one up and one down) and so of course unpowered when the switches are set the same (both up or both down). I *think* this would be the conventional arrangement for the 3-wire control.

I can think of one practical reason to adhere to this convention. If one is using modern active switches that consume power to operate, then the double throw switch must have both a neutral connection and a line hot connection.

The 3-wire control arrangement has a (constant) line hot in both switch boxes at a particular contact and this does not change even momentarily when either switch is flipped.

In the 2-wire control arrangement the line hot in one box is momentarily interrupted every time the switch is changed in the other box and the hot changes from one contact to another. This works OK for simple mechanical switches, but I would think, but don't know for a fact, that the power consuming smart switches might require one particular contact to be the one connected to (always on) line hot.

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping the colours would indicate the non-common connections but in one wiring scheme the live wire is connected to a common connection while in the other it is connected to a non-common connection...

Comment: No, with the old arrangement (exactly) one of the travellers is always live, otherwise the remote switch wouldn't be able to choose between them.

Comment: OK, one does have to place the switches in the intermediate position to distinguish with a non-contact voltage tester. And we must assume that the tester will respond positively if any of the three contacts on the switch is at line voltage, which may not be the case. It is possible that the tester will respond only when the common is at line voltage.

Comment: It would not be much trouble to just remove the cover plates (US switch plate) so the end of the non contact tester could be placed near the contacts.

Comment: An alternative assumption is that the non contact tester signals if and only if the common is hot. See EDIT3. Of course, this assumption is designed to provide a basis for a test; it is possible but may not be true, would have to be tested by experimentation.

Comment: I was confused by the wiring of the 3-wire arrangement but I think I get it now. I've taken a picture of one of the other switches (the other is in a triple gang so that will only make things more confusing) and I think it clears up that this is a 3-wire arrangement, but could you confirm that?

Comment: The presence of four different colored wires indicates to me that this is 3-wire control, but you can tell for sure if the backs of both switches are exposed. Might have to have a voltmeter though. In the 3-wire the two commons are connected by a wire. In the 2-wire the common of one switch is connected to line hot andvthe onion of the other is connected to the load.

Comment: Actually if I've understood correctly the 3-wire has the regular switch loop connected to the two poles of the first switch, then the 3-wire cable connects the two switches together, common to common as you say, but also both pairs of poles, which seems to be what I'm seeing (see second picture from my edit).

Comment: Yes, in the 3-wire arrangement corresponding poles are connected *and* the commons are connected. In the 2-wire arrangement the two commons are not connected toveach other.

Comment: That's the explanation I needed! Answer accepted.

Comment: Made another edit to my answer.

Comment: I cannot read the backs of these switches to distinguish common, L1, and L2. The UK colour code has changed with time so I can't tell which wires you should switch to change to light on when the switches are set opposite.

Comment: The second switch has five wires. According to the diagram in the page you linked to, the power in and out are also joined to the travellers. The remaining yellow wire must therefore be the common.

Comment: What is the colour of the neutral and the color of the line hot in your house's wiring? How many distinct connection points are there on these switches? Looks like the switches are not of the same design. The important thing is to identify the wires which in the US are called "travelers" connecting the two switches. These are the ones to switch in exactly one switch. Having so many wires almost means you need a voltage tester to find out which is the line hot from the house wiring. To be sure it would really help to get info from someone familiar with UK wiring. Look for @RedGrittyBrick.

Comment: No matter, I have completed the job and it went smoothly thanks to your help in identifying the wiring arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

Swap the travelers and that will reverse the switch position.  Note: make sure NOT to swap the common, as if this is done, the switch combinations won’t all work.

Comment: Note that you need to swap the travelers *at one end only*. If you swap them at both ends, nothing will change.

Answer (score 1):

This is how 3-way switches work. Between the two switches is the neutral and two "travelers" with the travelers acting as the hot conductor. When any combination of switch positions connect two travelers, the circuit is connected and the light is on.

In my experience, flipping *either* switch will *toggle* the current state of the lights controlled by the switches. Switch position (up/down) has nothing to do with it. Heck, you could have one installed up/down and the other installed left/right and they'd still act as state toggles, not as "up = on", "down = off"

If you're *really* picky about it, you can reset them so both are down when the power is off, but that means you have to walk back and forth between the switches to get them the way you want them. This also means that, effectively, you can only use one switch and must always turn the lights on (that switch up) and off (that switch down) from that switch position while the other switch remains in the down position.

Comment: Whoever installed it didn't wire it like that, so the lights are off with exactly one switch flipped, when I want that to be the case when the lights are on.

Comment: That's most unusual, @Neil. I've got a 3-way switch on my kitchen lights. Flipping either switch toggles the light state. Maybe the difference is US vs UK - here "3-way" means 2 switches. I believe there it means 3 switches (which we'd call "4-way"). Don't know why we add an additional "way"...

Comment: Thanks, I meant to write 2-way, I have no idea why I consistently typed 3 by mistake.

Comment: US and UK call them differently. In EE in general they're called 2-way or double-throw. Some smart American marketing (so I believe) turned it into 3-way because 3 is more than 2.

Comment: They are single pole double throw, There are at least 3 different positions both up  or both down or one up and 1 down. It is a simple task of reversing the travelers as I answered. In the US we can rotate the switch but it looks like there is a marked top on in the photo so switching the travelers can get it where 1 state is exactly what you want by swapping the travelers on 1 switch.

Comment: @EdBeal Rotating the switch wouldn't help me anyway as there are two switches so they will become swapped.

Comment: Neil I fully understand that and that is the reason I provided the only thing that will partially help in my answer, swap a traveler and both switches in the up will be on , one up one down will be off ether side,  and last both down will be on you can reverse it by swapping travelers but there will be 3 states both up or down and mixed (ether up and down.)

Comment: There are four states for the pair of switches identified 1 and 2: 1 up, 2 up; 1 up, 2 down; 1 down, 2 up; 1 down, 2 down.  The switches are distinguishable so there are two distinct states where the switches are set differently.